# Are there plastic materials that turn into ceramics?

Tags: materials

Are there other materials that like clay, are plastic (as in they can be shaped by hand) but set to form a hard ceramic, especially ones harder than the fired clay?

Comment: Basically all ceramic materials match that description.

Answer (score 2):

The set of compounds you are looking for are known as [Thermosetting Polymers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermosetting_polymer). A few examples of these are:

- [Bakelite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bakelite): This is used for making switches and electrical enclosures
- [Melamine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melamine_resin): This is commonly used for making food grade and microwaveable utensils and is an alternative to ceramic (at least in the food packaging industry)

You might also want to take a look at [Thermoplastic Polymers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoplastic), as they behave a bit like wet clay (they become soft on heating and harden on cooling and this can be done as many number of times as required)

Comment: Hmm,but organic polymers can hardly compete with ceramic hardness.

Comment: "edible" means "can be eaten and digested, without harming your health"